# Where are my bookmarks?

Tags: bug, bookmarks

It seems that there is no tab "bookmarks" anymore in the activity section of the profile. Are all my bookmarks gone? Will they come back? If not, can the bookmarks be recovered?

Will the same happen to the "following" tab? There I save interesting questions/ answers and it would be problematic if the list would be deleted, too.

Comment: same issue with my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update Oct 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019)**

> Saves has been temporarily disabled network-wide due to some site performance problems. These problems didn't appear until partway through migrating existing bookmarks into saves. We've temporarily reverted back to Bookmarks.

> All saves, private notes, saved lists, and migrated bookmarks are unavailable. They are still saved in the database and will be available again when we turn Saves back on.

> All unmigrated bookmarks are currently available while Saves is disabled and Bookmarks is turned on. When we turn Saves on again, we'll resume the migration.

---

**Update 2 Oct 5**

Site is stable again.

Saves is enabled again for all users network wide. Your saves, saved lists, private notes, and migrated bookmarks should be available to you now. Bookmarks that were made during the outage period will be unavailable until we finish migrating tonight.

All bookmarks should migrate tonight. Until then, sites are either fully migrated or not migrated. The only exception is Stack Overflow which is still partially migrated with 360k of 14mil bookmarks migrated.

We have a maintenance window planned starting at 00:00 UTC. If all goes as expected, it should be done by 02:00 UTC.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-are-evolving-into-saves). It seems that the bookmarked threads will be migrated to the new feature "saves".

---

The new tool actually looks nice.